# com0com RS232 terminal Java program

Tags: java, terminal, serial-port, com0com

I made a Java program that runs on a computer with two RS-232 ports.

It works pretty good. I connected two devices that communicate with each other through RS-232. I put the computer between the cable.

You can see everything getting send on a terminal window.

But after a random amount of time one device stops responding to queries.

Normally device 1 sends query 1 and the device responds.

But after some time the device starts sending query 2 and device 2 doesn't respond anymore.

Here is a capture:

- First column: COM port id
- Second column: decimal presentation of the character
- Third column: visualization of characters

[image: https://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j74/bertyhell/errors/capture.png?t=1281084570]

Why is this not working? I'm planning on making the terminal program open source in the future.

EDIT:
I didn't post any code because the code works. It only stops working after 5 min - 1 hour.

Here is the connection code:

```
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier;
    portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM1");
    InputStream inCom1;
    InputStream inCom2;
    if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
        addError("COM1 in use!, please restart");
    }
    else {
        SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) portIdentifier.open("Main", 2000);
        //19200 8n1
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(19200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        // CTS/RTS handshaking
        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);
        //Set sender
        Com1Sender.setWriterStream(serialPort.getOutputStream());
        //Set receiver
        //    new com1_receive(serialPort.getInputStream()).start();

        inCom1 = serialPort.getInputStream();

        portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM2");
        if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
            addError("COM2 in use!, please restart");
        }
        else {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portIdentifier.open("Main2", 2001);
            //19200 8n1
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(19200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            // CTS/RTS handshaking
            serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);
            //Set sender
            Com2Sender.setWriterStream(serialPort.getOutputStream());
            //set receiver
            //    new com2_receive(serialPort.getInputStream()).start();

            inCom2 = serialPort.getInputStream();
            new Receiver(inCom1, inCom2).start();
        }
    }
```

This is the receiver:

```
    public class Receiver extends Thread {
        InputStream inCom1;
        InputStream inCom2;

        public Receiver(InputStream inCom1, InputStream inCom2) {
            this.inCom1 = inCom1;
            this.inCom2 = inCom2;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int b1;
                int b2;
                while (true) {
                    // if stream is not bound in.read() method returns -1

                    //dect
                    while ((b1 = inCom1.read()) != -1) {
                        //Send trough to COM2
                        Com2Sender.send(new byte[]{(byte) b1});
                        Main.addText(Integer.toString(b1), true);
                    }

                    //televic
                    while ((b2 = inCom2.read()) != -1) {
                        //Send trough to COM2
                        Com1Sender.send(new byte[]{(byte) b2});
                        Main.addText(Integer.toString(b2), false);
                        MessageExtractor.add(b2);
                    }

                    // Wait 10 ms when stream is broken and check again.
                    sleep(10);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Main.addError(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

This is one of the senders:

```
    public class Com1Sender {
        static OutputStream out;

        public static void setWriterStream(OutputStream out) {
            Com1Sender.out = out;
        }

        public static void send(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                // Sending through serial port is simply writing into OutputStream.
                out.write(bytes);
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void send(int letter) {
            try {
                Main.addText(Character.toString((char)letter), false);

                // Sending through serial port is simply writing into OutputStream.
                out.write(new byte[]{(byte)letter});
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll find that if you post some key pieces of code, the coders will much more information to help you with an answer.  For example, precisely how are you reading and writing to/from the ports?

Comment: ok added code
hope it doesn't scare ppl away ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out what the problem is, so I'm going to try it with [a physical cable](http://www.commfront.com/RS232_Protocol_Analyzer_Monitor/RS232_Spy_Monitor_Cable_Half_Duplex.htm).

Or if you're handy, *[a RS-232 serial spy monitor cable](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/cable/RS-232-spy-monitor.html)*.